# hard drive data retrieval

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

My Ubuntu 18.04 crashed a few days back. I installed Ubuntu 20.04. May be my question is naive but is there any way I can retrieve data from the previous Ubuntu 18.04 version ?

Regards,
Amit.

Comment: please [edit] your question to provide further information. For example, what is the status of the old drive? was 20.04 installed over the original installation or is the disk preserved and replaced with a new disk? You question is short of much detail to provide any meaningful answer as it stands.

Comment: I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on the same drive which had 18.04

Comment: That was a bad idea if you want to keep data... Now you need to use recovery tools (e.g. photorec or foremost) and hope that the data you want to retrieve was not overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You can recover some data, but you're almost certainly going to have lost a lot of it.

First, **stop using the computer entirely until you are ready to recover data.** The more you use the computer before data recovery, the more data will be written to the drive, and the more data that you write to the drive, the less data there is to recover.

To prepare for data recovery, go to a different computer than the one that you lost data on, and download a live ISO that contains PhotoRec. I've had success using a KaOS ISO for this purpose, using QPhotoRec. I'll assume this is the ISO you're using. Download the ISO and flash it to a USB drive using a tool like balenaEtcher.

Next, get a large external hard drive (WD EasyStore drives are cheap and big, you can get them at Best Buy), and have it ready for the data recovery operation. You're going to save the recovered data to this drive.

Now, insert the USB drive into the system with the lost data, and boot the system from the USB drive. Once you're fully booted into the live environment, plug your external hard drive in.

Next, open KDE Partition Manager, select the external hard drive, delete the existing partition(s) on the external drive, and create a new ext4 partition on it. **Make sure you're doing this to the external drive, not the internal one!**

Next, open QPhotoRec, select the partition on your main drive that used to contain your data, and have QPhotoRec save the recovered data to the external drive. Start the recovery procedure, and wait. It may take a very long time.

Once you're done, you can now scroll through the recovered data within the live environment. You'll have lost all directory structure, but you should be able to recover a decent chunk of your data, depending on what all you were storing in there. If you're satisfied with the results, shutdown the computer, boot it normally, and resume usage. If you're missing critical data and need to keep trying, you can try to recover more data by using PhotoRec directly (rather than QPhotoRec), and tweaking the settings, or you can try other data recovery software. Sadly, you almost certainly won't be able to recover everything.

Once you've recovered everything you can, sort through your data and transfer it back onto your computer, and then use the external hard drive for backups.